# Algorithm for orthogonal polynomials

Tags: algorithm, math, octave

and thank you for the attention you're paying to my question :)

My question is about finding an (efficient enough) algorithm for finding orthogonal polynomials of a given weight function f.

I've tried to simply apply the Gram-Schmidt algorithm but this one is not efficient enough. Indeed, it requires O(n^2) integrals. But my goal is to use this algorithm in order to find [Hankel determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) of a function f. So a "direct" computation wich consists in simply compute the matrix and take its determinants requires only 2*n - 1 integrals.

But I want to use the theorem stating that the Hankel determinant of order n of f is a product of the n first leading coefficients of the orthogonal polynomials of f. The reason is that when n gets larger (say about 20), Hankel determinant gets really big and my goal is to divided it by an other big constant (for n = 20, the constant is of order 10^103). My idea is then to "dilute" the computation of the constant in the product of the leading coefficients.

I hope there is a O(n) algorithm to compute the n first orthogonal polynomials :) I've done some digging and found nothing in that direction for general function f (f can be any smooth function, actually).

EDIT: I'll precise here what the objects I'm talking about are.

1) A Hankel determinant of order n is the determinant of a square matrix which is constant on the skew diagonals. Thus for example

a b c

b c d

c d e

is a Hankel matrix of size 3 by 3.

2) If you have a function f : R -> R, you can associate to f its "kth moment" which is defined as (I'll write it in tex) f_k := \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) x^k dx

With this, you can create a Hankel matrix A_n(f) whose entries are (A_n(f))*{ij} = f*{i+j-2}, that is something of the like

f_0 f_1 f_2

f_1 f_2 f_3

f_2 f_3 f_4

With this in mind, it is easy to define the Hankel determinant of f which is simply
H_n(f) := det(A_n(f)). (Of course, it is understood that f has sufficient decay at infinity, this means that all the moments are well defined. A typical choice for f could be the gaussian f(x) = exp(-x^2), or any continuous function on a compact set of R...)

3) What I call orthogonal polynomials of f is a set of polynomials (p_n) such that

\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) p_j(x) p_k(x) is 1 if j = k and 0 otherwize.

(They are called like that since they form an orthonormal basis of the vector space of polynomials with respect to the scalar product

(p|q) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) p(x) q(x) dx

4) Now, it is basic linear algebra that from any basis of a vector space equipped with a scalar product, you can built a orthonormal basis thanks to the [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). This is where the n^2 integrations comes from. You start from the basis 1, x, x^2, ..., x^n. Then you need n(n-1) integrals for the family to be orthogonal, and you need n more in order to normalize them.

5) There is a theorem saying that if f : R -> R is a function having sufficient decay at infinity, then we have that its Hankel determinant H_n(f) is equal to

H_n(f) = \prod_{j = 0}^{n-1} \kappa_j^{-2}

where \kappa_j is the leading coefficient of the j+1th orthogonal polynomial of f.

Thank you for your answer!

(PS: I tagged octave because I work in octave so, with a bit of luck (but I doubt it), there is a built-in function or a package already done managing this kind of think)

Comment: Your problem statement is a little confusing as you mix continuous and discrete elements, and you don't define the "determinant" of a function.

Comment: You need to be far more specific.  What sort of space are we talking about? Reals?  Function f maps reals to reals or integers to reals or something else?   Where does this number O(n^2) come from?  The naive approach would be to calculate integrals over `f*x^a * x^b` for `a,b` in the range `0..n-1`.  This would mean you need only integrals over `f*x^k`, for `k=0..2*n-2`, right?

Comment: I eddited my post to precise what the objects are. I hope its precise enough now :)

Answer (score 3):

Orthogonal polynomials obey a recurrence relation, which we can write as

```
P[n+1] = (X-a[n])*P[n] - b[n-1]*P[n-1]
P[0] = 1
P[1] = X-a[0]
```

and we can compute the a, b coefficients by

```
a[n] = <X*P[n]|P[n]> / c[n]
b[n-1] = c[n-1]/c[n]
```

where

```
c[n] = <P[n]|P[n]>
```

(Here < | > is your inner product).

However I cannot vouch for the stability of this process at large n.

Comment: Additionally, a more detailed description of the three-term recurrence relation for orthogonal polynomials can be found [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/PartIB/Lect03.pdf) (section 2.3)